# How can I use googles document editing services to my website?

Tags: google-api, cloud, google-drive-api

I would like to be able to integrate google docs functions to my own website. How could I use googles api but store documents on my own server?

I have seen some solutions such as https://owncloud.com/owncloud-overview . But I was wondering if google had its own solution or if there is something better out there?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. At most you can sync them with your server.